# Setting base category for margins in Stata

Tags: stata, radix, margins

I am calculating marginal effects from a logistic regression in Stata. I need the base of `quantilev2` to be set to 2, however the default is set to 3. I have the following code and output.

```
fvset base 3 quantilev2
logit returnv customer_age i.customer_gender return_ratio_customer total_past_orders avg_ordersize relationship_length total_rela_value price i.pricesegment2 discount_value discount_ratio return_ratio_product i.category2 brand2 i.quantilev2 basket_size diff_prod_cat same_item same_item_diff_size product_number_within_order i.quantilev2#c.basket_size
```

```
margins, dydx(quantilev2) at(basket_size=0.205471) at(basket_size=7.3485774) at(basket_size=14.449777) pwcompare
```

The margins command then gives the following output

```
Expression: Pr(returnv), predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.quantilev2 2.quantilev2
1._at: basket_size =  .205471
2._at: basket_size = 7.348577
3._at: basket_size = 14.44978

---------------------------------------------------------------
              |   Contrast Delta-method         Unadjusted
              |      dy/dx   std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
--------------+------------------------------------------------
1.quantilev2  |
          _at |
      2 vs 1  |  -.0064799    .002717     -.0118052   -.0011546
      3 vs 1  |  -.0128849   .0053998     -.0234683   -.0023015
      3 vs 2  |  -.0064049   .0026827      -.011663   -.0011469
--------------+------------------------------------------------
2.quantilev2  |
          _at |
      2 vs 1  |   .0084133   .0035772      .0014022    .0154244
      3 vs 1  |   .0167195   .0070962      .0028111    .0306279
      3 vs 2  |   .0083062   .0035191      .0014089    .0152035
--------------+------------------------------------------------
3.quantilev2  |  (base outcome)
---------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the
      base level.
```

Comment: So, why not try `fvset base 3 quantilev2`  ?

Comment: This works for the regression, however in the margins this does not work. I see now I forgot to include the margins command, so I will change that.

Comment: Someone else may be able to help further.